# xpath issues with multiple tags

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am working on Java - Selenium. My code looks like below

```
<a _ngcontent-c6="" class="main-body-text" tabindex="0">Read more about <span _ngcontent-c6="" class="lowercase">Appointments.</span></a>
```

I tried

```
//a[text()= 'Read more about ']   and
//span[contains(text(),'Appointments.')]
```

selects two separate links but when I want to check for link exist or not - It is not working. How to write xpath for this ?

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Appointments.')]")
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[normalize-space(text())='Read more about']")
```

Want single xpath for above two conditions.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? do you want to combine text ?

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML?

Comment: Please see the code added. I want to check whether this link is active or not. I have written two methods for this. Shown below.

Answer (score 0):

Variants to get the `a`:
 1. `//a[contains(., 'Read more about') and contains(.,'Appointments')]`
 2. `//a[contains(., 'Read more about') and ./span[.='Appointments.']]`

Variants to get the `span`:
 1. `//a[contains(., 'Read more about') and contains(.,'Appointments')]/span`
 2. `//a[contains(., 'Read more about') and ./span[.='Appointments.']]/span`
 3. `//span[.='Appointments.' and ./ancestor::a[contains(., 'Read more about')][1]]`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am trying to check whether link works or not. I am getting response as NULL instead of 200. When clicked on link it works fine. Above xpath is giving me same output NULL. It is not allowing me to add my code. I will try to add code.

Comment: public boolean verifyBrokenLinks(String pagename, String linkname,  WebElement element) {
 boolean status = true;
 try {
  String href = getAttribute(element, "href");
  if (!href.isEmpty()) {
   URL url = new URL(href);
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   con.connect();
   int resCode = con.getResponseCode();
   if (resCode == 200) {
    logStatus("PASS");
   } else {
    logStatus("FAIL");
   }
  } else {
   logStatus("FAIL");
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  status = false;
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 return status;
}

Comment: public String getAttribute(WebElement element, String attribute) {
  String data = "";

  try {
   data = element.getAttribute(attribute);
   System.out.println("getAttribute method");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("In exception condition get attribute !" + e.getMessage());
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  return data;

 }

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. After posting my code realized that there is no href. so my code is wrong. Sorry for taking your time. My apologies and thanks again.